# ArcGIS Pro - routing, remove short network elements and reconnect edges

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, topology, network

I am setting up an ArcGIS Pro network for use in Network Analyst. So far things work pretty well, depart from some 1600 errors due to this kind of problem: "

> SourceName: linknetz, ObjectID: 1369061, The edge feature is too small to participate in snapping and may not be connected to other features.

These network elements have a dimension (length) varying between 0,001 to 0,01 meters. according to the above mentioned error message these short lines are not implemented as egdes and as a consequence the resulting network is fragmented and has gaps at the respective sections.
so I was looking for a method to eliminate lines < 0,5m and close the resulting gaps automatically in a topologically correct way. but so far didn't find anything suitable.
... I remember ArcInfo tools that provided this kind of functionality.

Comment: meanwhile i have implementet a geodatabase topology on top of a feature dataset and feature class. the "must not have dangles" could be part of my solution. i use "could" by intention - because if I delete any line below a length threshold the number of dangles is increasing - so if i had a way to select just those that have length-values below my threshold and fix the gaps by running a "fix errors" sequence these gaps would be closed without changing the existing valid danglies (i.e. the existing dead end roads)

Comment: Select shorties (mark them) and do select by location on itself. Delete shorties and snap what left to nodes, if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

My task was to set up a mixed/multimodal network with a GTFS public transport section and a streetnetwork. With a little help from the esri-distributor/support i've found my way through that problem - their hint was to use INTEGRATE instead of struggling with a geodatabase topology approach:

- at first I did a NEAR-step to find the points on the street-network
  that are the closest to my stop-points -> StopsOnStreets.
- Next step was to identify StopsOnStreets that are too close to each other via a user-defined threshold.
- With PAIRWISE INTEGRATE and the threshold these "close Points" were moved into their "center of gravity"-location.
- With another NEAR-step I identified the point on the streetnetwork that is closest to this center-of-gravity-point - NewStopsOnStreets.
- A set of lines was then created between Stops and NewStopsOnStreets --> StopConnectors.
- With these NewStopsOnStreets I did a SPLIT LINES AT POINTS I split
  the streetnetwork at the locations where my virtual passengers pass
  by on their way from Origins by using the streetnetwork to the
  NewStopsOnStreets, passing the StopConnectors, reaching the stops
  this way and change into the PublicTransportNetork